# How to analyse a music file (mp3) in order to display its spectrum on Mobile using J2ME - Java ME

Tags: java, java-me

Now I want to create a simple media player for Mobile. It will read a music file (default : mp3), then play it and display spectrum on screen. But now I don't know how to analyse a music file. Please tell me way to analyse it. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to parse the input files in order to get to the samples. Instead you can [capture the sound](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0430__J2ME/CapturePlaybackAudio.htm) currently played to get your hands on the raw audio data. To draw a spectrum visualization of this you would have to perform a FFT on this data and the use the result to render your bars (or whatever you choose for you visuals).

Comment: Your're welcome. NB: That "up" arrow to the left of the answer is the usual way to say thanks on SO. :-)

Comment: Can you tell me more about way to get raw audio date ? I code J2ME, can I use AudioRecord API ?

Comment: @waldheinz: Do you mean the Android AudioRecord class? chenglingwo is asking for a J2ME solution.

Comment: @chenglingwo and @jarnbjo: I'm biased and associated java+mobile=android, I edited accordingly with a link to a J2ME example. Sorry for the confusion.